# Problem when using the "using" keyword

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using the "using" keyword to load a dialog where the user enters the captcha code from a webpage, but the problem is the dialog is loading and closing instantly. How can I ensure the dialog waits for user input?

```
using (Form2 captchaDialog = new Form2(captchaImage))
{
    captchaDialog.Show();
    captchaText = captchaDialog.captcha;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use `ShowDialog` method instead:

```
using (Form2 captchaDialog = new Form2(captchaImage))
{
    captchaDialog.ShowDialog();
    captchaText = captchaDialog.captcha;
}
```

Comment: @Dave -- which will block until the user has finished.

Answer (score 3):

Your form is closing immediately because your code hits the end of the `using` block which will dispose the newly created form, which in turn close the form if it is open. You have to block your call to the dialog by using `ShowDialog`.

```
using (var dialog = new Form2(captchaImage))
{
    if(dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        captchaText = captchaDialog.captcha;
    }
}
```